# Simultaneously load all pages in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to developing apps with shiny dashboard. I have built an complex shiny app with 12 menus. After loading the dataset, each page gets loaded only On clicking the menu. This takes a lot of processing time.

I want to know whether on loading the dataset in the shiny app, is it possible to load all the pages in shiny app simultaneously instead of waiting for the menu to be clicked.

Please give your inputs for solving the issue.

Thanks in Advance,
SJB.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50777671/8037249) I posted recently can help you in the right direction.